# NUnit Categories not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit

I want to custom group my tests by function so I'm using the nunit Category attribute, like this:

```
[Test, Category("Cat1")]
public void SomeMethod() { }

[Test, Category("Cat2")]
public void AnotherMethod() { }
```

But in Visual Studio the categories do not show up, all I see are the defaults to group by duration or test outcome. I'm using:

- NUnit 2.6.4
- Visual Studio 2012
- NUnit Test Adapter 2.0.0.0

What am I missing? This seems like it should be a no-brainer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to group your tests by `Traits`, which includes the `Category` attribute.  If you can't then you may need to update [your Visual Studio to at least Update 1](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3090310-allow-tests-to-be-grouped-by-class-category-and).  A more detailed description, targeted at the MS framework is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx) but the TestAdapter seems to allow it to work just fine with the NUnit Category attribute.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the info. VIsual Studio is one of those things I usually install and then don't touch until I install the next major version, I need to be better about keeping my working version updated.